# What is considered truthy or falsy in expressions contexts in GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

> How does GitHub Actions evaluate expressions for non-existing outputs?

Are references to non-existing outputs and/or variables falsy in expression contexts in GitHub Actions? I can't find anything in the documentation about what is considered truthy or falsy.

In the workflow below, `deploy` doesn't run, since `needs.init.outputs.foobar` is undefined (?).

In general, what is considered truthy or falsy in expression contexts in GitHub Actions?

Bonus: do undefined outputs and environment variables evaluate to `null` , empty string, or something else?

```
jobs:
  init:
    name: Init
    runs-on: [self-hosted, myapp]
    timeout-minutes: 10
    outputs:
      foobar: ${{ steps.setenv.outputs.foobar }}
    steps:
      - name: Set environment
        id: setenv
        run: echo "HelloWorld!"

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    uses: ./.github/workflows/deploy.yml
    secrets: inherit
    concurrency: deploy
    needs: [init]
    if: needs.init.outputs.foobar
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#about-expressions

Comment: I read [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#outputs-for-docker-container-and-javascript-actions) that outputs are Unicode strings, and can be a maximum of 1 MB. What I use to do is to set the value to `true` or `false` in a setup job, to then use an if expression like `if: {{ needs.init.outputs.foobar == 'true' }}` to run a sequencial job or not.

Comment: Thank you, but in my case `if: needs.init.outputs.foobar` is evaluated to `false`. I can't believe it's not documented anywhere

Comment: It might be the default behavior. I indeed didn't find this information anywhere there as well.